# Image bug with Polymer paper-tabs

Tags: css, polymer

I have a weird bug with Polymer and I don't know how to solve it. My code is the following:

```
<paper-tabs attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{data.page}}"><paper-tab data-route="profile" on-tap="scrollTop">Profile</paper-tab>
<paper-tab data-route="admin" on-tap="scrollTop">Admin panel</paper-tab>
<paper-tab data-route="users" on-tap="scrollTop">Users</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

<iron-image sizing="contain" id="player-avatar" src="[[user.avatar]]"></iron-image>
```

I'm trying to make my iron-image rounded by attaching the following style to it: border-radius: 50%

I have debugged my problem and found what caused it. Inside of paper-tabs there is a div with an ID of selectionBar. I looked at this div's styles and toggled them on and off. When I toggled the transform style off my image became rounded like it should've.

```
transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px) scaleX(0);
```

I've spent too much time trying to fix this and so I decided to ask others' suggestion.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to use iron image? Wouldn't a standard img be OK? You can still dynamically bind to it like <img src$="[user.avatar]">

Comment: Yeah, that would work. Do you have any clue regarding the problem?

Comment: I did not find any reason, sorry